# RXJS update Subject similar to Svelte stores?

Tags: rxjs, svelte, subject

is there a way to update RXJS Subjects like Svelte stores with an instance of the current value?
Currently I have:

```
const materials = someMethodToGetResults();
const tmp = this.activeFilters.value;
tmp.materials = materials;
this.activeFilters.next(tmp);
```

which is not very elegant in my opinion. I always need to update the whole object where I only really need to update the properties. I think Svelte solves this super elegant, the stores have an update method like this:

```
this.activeFilters.update(current => {
  current.materials = someMethodToGetResults();
  return current;
});
```

Am I missing something? RXJS has a quite steep learning curve.
Thanks.

Comment: A Subject is not a store.  It simply provides a mechanism to push a value to subscribers.   You could use RxJS Subjects as part of the solution of creating your own "Store" class that has the functionality you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in subject like this, but you can build your own

```js
export class StoreSubject extends BehaviorSubject {
   update(updateFn) {
     this.next(updateFn(this.getValue());
   }
}
```

Usage:

```js
const store = new StoreSubject(initialValue);
// .. later:
store.update(val => {
  // do something
  return val
});
```